# rsync hanging up reproducable on the same file while copying to nfs share

Tags: nfs, rsync, nfs4

For the last two days I try to backup my disc to an NFS share. But after a while rsync is hanging up itself. Every time on the same file. But if I exclude the file it'll hangup on the next file. So it isn't the file causing the problem at least not directly.

If I attache with strace to the process I see an ERESTARTNOHEAD error and a few timeouts. But I think these timeouts are not directly related to the problem because they appear also before the actual error. It seems that the ERESTARTNOHEAD is the problem but I can't find much about the this error.

The systems are a Debian oldstable as NFS server and a Ubuntu 15.10 as client

The command was: rsync -av /home/myuser /nfs/backup

The output of strace:
[image]

Comment: what about the file itself ?
give more details about the options you pass to rsync while copying please.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `cp` have the same problem?

Comment: @pat I've updated the post to include the rsync call. The file itself is irrelevant, it is a picture, a text file, etc. depending on what I exclude.

Comment: I've also added a screenshot of the strace output

Comment: Why do people always need to take screenshots of **text**?

Comment: Are there any I/O errors on the client?

Comment: nope, no I/O errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred in a relation to TCP offloading enabled on the two hosts. After disabling the TCP offloading through ethtool the problems are gone.

Comment: Can to give the exact command that you used to disable the TCP offloading?